# Trying to Access the Name of the Parameter & Not its Value in R

Tags: r, function, parameters, word-cloud

I am trying to create a function that creates a *Wordcloud* that has for parameters, a data frame and one of its columns. However, there is a bug in the 1st statement. I want to have the '*DataFrame$Column*' pass as a parameter of VectorSource. How can I best achieve this?

```
  createsWordcloud <- function(df, col) {
      # An Object of Class VectorSource which extends the Class Source representing a vector where each entry is interpreted as a document.
      # Every Element of the Corpus is stored as a Document...
                                   # The Bug is right here!..
      corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(paste(df, "$", col, sep="")))

      # Convert the Corpus to Plain Text Document
      corpus  <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)

      # Remove Punctuation & STOPWORDS...
      # STOPWORDs are commonly used words in the English Language... i.e. I, me, my
      # To view the full list of STOPWORDS, type stopwords('english') in the Console...
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))

      # Next we perform STEMMING... All the words will be converted to their stem
      # i.e. learning -> learn, walked -> walk
      # These Words will be Plotted Only Once!
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)

      wordcloud(corpus, max.words=100, random.order=FALSE)
      # These parameters are used to limit the number of words plotted. 
      # max.words will plot the specified number of words and discard least frequent terms, 
      # whereas, min.freq will discard all terms whose frequency is below the specified value.
    }
```

Comment: Stop trying to use `$`. Use `[[` instead, `df[[col]]`. `$` is good for interactive use, not for programming.

Comment: Hadley Wickham has a [comprehensive guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) to this sort of hacking; well-worth reading if you want to use the language on this level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of accomplishing this; one uses non-standard evaluation.  Also, for your particular task, it may be feasible to simply pass in `df$col` and have the function take a vector instead of a data frame, since you only ever use that one column in the code given.

If you do need to pass in the column name, the standard way is to pass in the column name as a string, and reference it with the subset (`[.data.frame`) operator:

```
readcol <- function(df, col) {
  df[, col]
}
```

And then

```
> readcol(data.frame(x=1:10), "x")
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

### non-standard evaluation

If you really don't want to quote the name of the column, you need to do lazy evaluation on the `col` parameter to extract it from the data frame:

```
readcol.nse <- function(df, col) {
  eval(substitute(col), df, parent.frame())
}
```

And then

```
> readcol.nse(data.frame(x=1:10), x)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

The standard caveat applies here -- be very careful about non-standard evaluation.  It is difficult to use programmatically (since passing a column name through to another function is tricky) and can have unintuitive side effects with more complex expressions.  The string form is a little more unwieldy, but is more composable.